# Set background color of MaterialSpinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am using this (https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner) for my spinner in my project. The problem is i did't find any way to change the spinner's background. I've try to use `android:background="#fff"`, then try to use `android:theme="@style/myspinnertheme"` which is changeing the background but still did't work. I don't know another way i can try :D

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spCategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:ms_baseColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:ms_floatingLabelText="Kategori"
    app:ms_enableErrorLabel="true"
    app:ms_hint="Pilih Kategori : "/>
```

This is my project screen shoot :

[image]

Look at the spinner at bottom, i want to change the background color to white, what shall i do?

Comment: what is your xml look like?

Comment: i've edited my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because [material spinner](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner/blob/master/library/src/main/java/fr/ganfra/materialspinner/MaterialSpinner.java) set background resources in constructor and changes your background. So just reset background resources with your color. Example:

Create background.xml in drawable( colors for default, pressed and selected spinner's state)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And set it

```
    MaterialSpinner spinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spCategory);
    spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

Comment: how to change dropdown text appearance like textColor or textSize ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom:ms_baseColor="@color/green"